# How to identify number of lines for dynamic length label required for given string?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a UILabel with dynamic width and dynamic string which I am getting from server. Now I want to set this string to label as text. Also I need to set number of lines to label. As I am getting dynamic string so I am not sure how much characters can be set in a line.

I found similar answers but those are not giving me accuracy as I need.

Comment: if you found similar answers show your tried code so it becomes easy for other to answer in more covenant way

Comment: Have a look at this post https://iosnetwork.blogspot.in/2017/03/how-to-calculate-dynamic-height-of.html

Answer (score 1):

Set number of lines to 0, this will make it dynamic. You also need to make your UILabel sizeToFit`myUiLabel.sizeToFit()`

Answer (score 0):

If you for some reason need the number of lines, you can use following extension on `UILabel`:

```
extension UILabel {

    func linesNeeded() -> Int {
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        let myText = self.text! as NSString
        let boundingRectangle = CGSize(width: self.bounds.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)
        let labelSize = myText.boundingRect(with: boundingRectangle,
                                            options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                            attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font: self.font],
                                            context: nil)
        return (labelSize.height / self.font.lineHeight)
    }
}
```

However, if you don't need the height, you just want to allow the label to show the whole text, you should set `label.numberOfLines = 0` which will allow the label to grow as needed.